# Which class should I connect my open video menu item to?

Tags: swift, macos, model-view-controller

I'm developping a subtitling application in *Swift* for *OSX*. The app has a *Open...* menu to open a subtitling project, and a *Open video...* menu item. I wonder how should I connect the action to my current classes:

- AppDelegate
- Document
- Other (like VideoViewController)?

Since the video will be "linked" to the project in order that if we save the project and open it later, the video will be automatically linked.

I'd like to keep as close of the MVC paradigm.